# list of items 30 days old show how many updates after day 30

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like some examples showing how to create a report to list down,  all items over 30 days old in 2014, how many updates were done for each item after day 30? My table looks like:

`item   description   Start Date   End Date   Status   Last Update Date`

Thanks

Comment: All items in 2014 are over 30 days old

Comment: After what date should we look for the 30 days? Start / End / Last Update Date?

Answer (score 0):

Here my interpretation of your question.

V1:

```
-- all Items in 2014 with 'Last Update' >= 30 days, counting from the current day
SELECT 
    item, description, Start Date, End Date, Status, Last Update Date       
FROM myTable
WHERE Year(Start Date) = 2014
  AND DATEDIFF(Day, Last Update Date, GetDate()) >= 30
```

V2:

```
-- all items, description & status in 2014 with 'Last Update' >= 30 days, counting from the current day
-- grouped & count(*)
SELECT 
    item, description, Status, Count(*) AS Counter
FROM myTable
WHERE Year(Start Date) = 2014
  AND DATEDIFF(Day, Last Update Date, GetDate()) >= 30
GROUP BY item, description, status
```